# Find a document by one property of its nested document in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have this four schemas. Restroom schema has a property called Full address composed by the ids of Address, City and Region schemas. I don't know if there's a way to search all the restrooms available by the ZIP code property of the City schema, so if that ZIP code matches the one passed in the parameter of the request I get a list of all the corresponding restrooms.

```
const AddressSchema = new Schema<IAddress>(
  {
    street: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

```
const CitySchema = new Schema<ICity>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    zipCode: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

```
const RegionSchema = new Schema<IRegion>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

```
const RestroomSchema = new Schema<IRestroom>(
    {
        name: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        },
        avgRating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }, 
        fullAddress: {
            address: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'addresses', 
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'cities',
                required: true
            },
            region: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'regions',
                required: true
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false
    }
);
```

I was thinking of doing it this way that I found somewhere, but I don't know if it may be the right one.

```
RestroomModel.findOne({ _id: id })
             .populate({ path: 'fullAddress.address', populate: 'street' })
             .populate({ path: 'fullAddress.city', populate: 'zipCode' })
             .populate({ path: 'fullAddress.region', populate: 'name'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`match`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) to filter `fullAddress.city.zipCode` on population:

```
RestroomModel.findOne({ _id: id })
  .populate({ path: 'fullAddress.address' })
  .populate({ path: 'fullAddress.region' })
  .populate({ 
    path: 'fullAddress.city',
    match: { zipCode: "Some zip code" }
  });
```